# Autolayout mixing code and interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, autolayout

I would like to use Autolayout in my project

Ideally I would like to have xib where I "pre-arrange" my views approx possition and height and all outlets and actions to the master.

Then I would like in - viewDidLoad addConstraints to all views so they re-arrange

Is this even good solution? How I should proceed set xib to use autolayout ? Should I remove all constraints before I set my own ?

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just set up the constraints in IB if you've gone through the trouble of setting up the views? There are special cases where you might do that, but they're fairly unusual. Why not just set up the constraints in IB? It's generally much easier to do it that way.

Comment: A good solution to what? I'm with Rob, you should set them up in IB unless you're trying to do something that can't be done there. If you do add your own in code, yes, you generally do have to remove the ones you setup in IB (or at least modify the constant value).

Comment: Well honestly I dont like interface builder that much. It seems that for complicated views i would click myself to death:) and I hate to always trying to click on those 1px lines. I like interface builder for fast mockuping but I preffer to code the views. I am not saying that its good aproach however thats why I asked the question and your comments were infact they made me think. P.S. in IB lot of constraints seems horrible mess to me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to do the following:

- Setup all necessary constraints in IB.
- Create outlets for constraints you need to change dynamically (if that's what you're trying to do)
- In your viewDidLoad method access these outlets and change the values

This way you get best parts of both worlds. You get UI for originally setting up all layout and then you can adjust it in run-time.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try to be honest I didnt even know you can outlet the constraints ... but maybe what is my goal is to fast setup the views and outlet them and do the precise positioning in code but yeah thats maybe wrong aproach.